# Nokogiri children method

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I have the following XML here:

```
<listing>
    <seller_info>
    <payment_types>Visa, Mastercard, , , , 0, Discover, American Express </payment_types>
    <shipping_info>siteonly, Buyer Pays Shipping Costs </shipping_info>
    <buyer_protection_info/>
    <auction_info>
    <bid_history>
    <item_info>
</listing>
```

The following code works fine for displaying first child of the first `//listing` node:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri' 

html_data = open('http://aiweb.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/xmltk/xmldata/data/auctions/321gone.xml')

nokogiri_object = Nokogiri::XML(html_data)
listing_elements = nokogiri_object.xpath("//listing")

puts listing_elements[0].children[1]
```

This also works:

```
puts listing_elements[0].children[3]
```

I tried to access the second node `<payment_types>` with the the following code:

```
puts listing_elements[0].children[2]
```

but a blank line was displayed. Looking through Firebug, it is clearly the 2nd child of the listing node. In general, only odd numbers work with the children method.

Is this a bug in Nokogiri? Any thoughts?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Remove the image and instead paste the markup into the question after stripping it to the bare minimum that still demonstrates the problem, formatting it appropriately. We have to retype the information to use it instead of being able to copy/paste it, which slows us, induces errors, and makes it so your question can't be indexed by the search engines. A link to the page only wastes our time as it forces us to sift through that page, doing what is your responsibility. http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idm46680517890864 is useful reading too.

Comment: done,  @theTinMan

Comment: The problem is your (mis)use of `children`. See my code below.

Comment: I agree with @theTinMan regarding `children` but all you have to do is use `element_children` instead, which behaves the way you thought it did. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bug, its the space created while parsing strings that contain `"\n"` (or empty nodes), but you could use the `noblanks` option to avoid them:

```
nokogiri_object = Nokogiri::XML(html_data) { |conf| conf.noblanks }
```

Use that and you will have no *blanks* in your array.

Comment: Thank you, @Gerry. It fixed the confusion of the indexing too.  So using the option   `noblanks` is the way to go when parsing XML?

Comment: @Ben Yes, unless you need to take any specific action with those spaces.

Comment: @Ben check the output in console after parsing your document without `noblanks` and you'll see all those `"\n        "` lines.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are not parsing the document correctly. `children` returns more than you think, and its use is painting you into a corner.

Here's a simplified example of how I'd do it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(DATA.read)

auctions = doc.search('listing').map do |listing|
  seller_info = listing.at('seller_info')
  auction_info = listing.at('auction_info')

  hash = [:seller_name, :seller_rating].each_with_object({}) do |s, h|
    h[s] = seller_info.at(s.to_s).text.strip
  end

  [:current_bid, :time_left].each do |s|
    hash[s] = auction_info.at(s.to_s).text.strip
  end

  hash
end


__END__
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/xmltk/xmldata/data/auctions/321gone.dtd">
<root>
  <listing>
    <seller_info>
      <seller_name>537_sb_3 </seller_name>
      <seller_rating> 0</seller_rating>
    </seller_info>
    <auction_info>
      <current_bid> $839.93</current_bid>
      <time_left> 1 Day, 6 Hrs</time_left>
    </auction_info>
  </listing>

  <listing>
    <seller_info>
      <seller_name> lapro8</seller_name>
      <seller_rating> 0</seller_rating>
    </seller_info>
    <auction_info>
      <current_bid> $210.00</current_bid>
      <time_left> 4 Days, 21 Hrs</time_left>
    </auction_info>
  </listing>
</root>
```

After running, `auctions` will be:

```
auctions
# => [{:seller_name=>"537_sb_3",
#      :seller_rating=>"0",
#      :current_bid=>"$839.93",
#      :time_left=>"1 Day, 6 Hrs"},
#     {:seller_name=>"lapro8",
#      :seller_rating=>"0",
#      :current_bid=>"$210.00",
#      :time_left=>"4 Days, 21 Hrs"}]
```

Notice there are no empty text nodes to deal with because I told Nokogiri exactly which nodes to grab text from. You should be able to extend the code to grab any information you want easily.

A typically formatted XML or HTML document that displays nesting or indentation uses text nodes to provide that indenting:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT
```

Here's what your code is seeing:

```
doc.at('body').children.map(&:to_html)
# => ["\n" +
#    "    ", "<p>foo</p>", "\n" +
#    "  "]
```

The Text nodes are what are confusing you:

```
doc.at('body').children.first.class # => Nokogiri::XML::Text
doc.at('body').children.first.text # => "\n    "
```

If you don't drill down far enough you will pick up the Text nodes and have to clean up the results:

```
doc.at('body')
  .text # => "\n    foo\n  "
  .strip # => "foo"
```

Instead, explicitly find the node you want and extract the information:

```
doc.at('body p').text # => "foo"
```

In the suggested code above I used `strip` because the incoming XML had spaces surrounding some text:

```
h[s] = seller_info.at(s.to_s).text.strip
```

which is the result of the original XML creation code not cleaning the lines prior to generating the XML. So sometimes we have to clean up their mess, but the proper accessing of the node can reduce that a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `children` includes text nodes such as the whitespace between elements. If instead you use `element_children` you get just the child elements (i.e. the contents of the tags, not the surrounding whitespace).

Comment: what is the different between `children` and `element_children` both return a list of elements in the context of the example?

Comment: `children` returns elements and text nodes. `element_children` returns only elements. You were expecting the former to behave like the latter.

Comment: I find that building code based on `children` or even `element_children` results in having to check node names to see if it's what I want, instead of seeking for the node directly. There's occasions where I want to look at every child node, such as converting the XML to a hash, but usually I'm only concerned with cherry-picking information.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It helped me to learn about the gem. I used the `at` method to grab the information about a particular token. Appreciate them very much.

Comment: @theTinMan I agree, and think that people tend to stop and iterate way too early, when with carefully crafted XPath or CSS selectors you can go straight to what you want. Ben, I'm glad you figured that out.